# Card view carElevation не работает на андроид 5

Tags: android, java

Почему не работает card_view:cardElevation, нет вообще ни тени, ни отступа, как будто нет такого параметра, а вот в андроид 4 работает нормально.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="1dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/cardView2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cardElevation` — атрибут `CardView`, используемый для обратной совместимости с API < 21. Начиная с API 21 и выше, следует использовать новый атрибут, появившийся у `View` — `android:elevation`.

Таким образом, в вашем случае, вам нужно указать оба этих атрибута.

Comment: сделал так, но на андроид 5 она так же не работает,
пробовал еще card_view:elevation="5dp"
 
       <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp"
    android:elevation="5dp"

Comment: @falstaf ваш способ, к сожалению, не работает, может, можно как-то по-другому

Comment: @eldqs, попробуйте добавить также `card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`.

Comment: @falstaf спасибо работает